# Natural language to source code links

Tags: document-management, reporting, requirements-management

I want to connect documentation (user stories) to source code. So for example, in a hypothetical company there are 100 text files with user comments about anything (bugs, comments on certain functionalities etc). What i want; is an automatic way to relate these documents to the source code. Just find the links. So for example if a user says something like: ***well, "button A" is not working properly*** in one of the text files. I need a tool that will trace this sentence to the piece(s) of code that implement "button A" and report something like: well, this text file over there is related to this class over here.

I believe that fits into the tractability domain (documents/natural language to source code) but i cannot seem to find a tool that implements it.

Does anyone know a tool that does that?

P.S. the programming language is Java

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Should it also fix the bug along the lines, update the documentation, and release an update – no matter what programming language used and which OS targeted? :) A few more details can't hurt. Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your answer and fill the gaps. Good luck, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh i am sorry, i hope now its better :)

Comment: Yes, definitely! Would you think the [`nlp` tag](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/nlp/info) a good addition as well? I'm not sure, that area is out of my experience.

Comment: I wonder how such a thing shall be possible. Our application has ~30 different Ok Buttons. I can't imagine any AI to find out which button it is when I say "The Ok Button is not working properly"

Comment: It is just an example... Of course you don't expect it to work on _everything_ but if there is something like: "**the e-mail form is not working**" how many e-mail forms do you have on your site? and well, there can be the case that the tool might return multiple links, and that's acceptable.